# How to print spring kafka configurations in logs using log4j

Tags: logging, properties, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Is there a way to log all spring-kafka configurations in logs using log4j? I have tried using the following logger configurations in my application log4j2.yml, I could see all info and debug logs but not configurations. 
        - name: org.springframework.kafka
          additivity: false
          level: info/debug
          AppenderRef:
            - ref: SOME_APPENDER
Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 3):

I think you really need to worry only about properties applied to the Apache Kafka Client. That will cover Spring Kafka configuration, too. For this purpose you only need to configure `INFO` for `org.apache.kafka.clients` category.

And this is a log from one of my tests:

```
16:55:20.616 INFO  [main][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig] ConsumerConfig values: 
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 10
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [127.0.0.1:56505]
    check.crcs = true
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = blc
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = null
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 305000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 60000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Comment: Thanks, for me changing log level for package `org.apache.kafka.clients` helped to avoid a mess in logs on service start. As Kafka consumers with Spring Cloud Stream in Hoxton.SR1 has huge amount of config logs with INFO log level.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me...

```
Configutation:
  name: Default

  Properties:
    Property:
      name: log-path
      value: "logs"

  Appenders:

    Console:
      name: Console_Appender
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"

  Loggers:

      Root:
        level: warn
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: Console_Appender

      Logger:
        - name: org.apache.kafka
          level: info
          AppenderRef:
            - ref: Console_Appender
```

and

```
[INFO ] 2017-12-20 17:00:08.591 [main] ProducerConfig - ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    ...
```

Comment: I am aware of that org.apache.kafka logs all Kafka client properties but I wanted to log Spring Kafka properties. Example If I configure my  application with the following Spring Kafka props, I should be able to see those configs in my logs but these props are not showing as part of "org.apache.kafka"
`spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      enable-auto-commit: false
    listener:
      ack-mode: record`

Comment: Certain spring boot properties (specifically `consumer` and `producer`) set kafka properties; for example, `enable-auto-commit` sets the `enable.auto.commit` property in the kafka properties. We don't currently provide a built-in mechanism to log the spring-specific properties such as `ack-mode`, but you could add your own. Feel free to open a [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues) and we'll consider adding it to a future release. Contributions are welcome.

Comment: Thanks Gary for confirming that there is no default way to print Spring Kafka properties in logs.